# tvOS UICollectionView scrolldirection

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, tvos

I am currently playing around with the tvOS SDK.

I need a collectionView with multiple section and many items, but **only one row per section.** So the user can scroll **vertically through the sections** and **horizontally through the items** in the single row.

When I set the scrollDirection of the collectionViewFlowLayout to ".Horizontal", the sections and the items are all just in one row, which looks pretty shitty.

Is there another way to get this behaviour? I thought about multiple collectionViews in a scrollView, but this seems too complicated and overheaded for me.

Thanks in advance!

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would think the best and possibly only way to get around this will be to a table view of collection views.

Somebody correct me if I'm wrong but that's the way I would probably go about doing it. Hope it helps!

Comment: Haha nice, thanks, you are right. Never thought of that!

Comment: I tried this. Unfortunately this only works on iOS, not tvOS. The scrolling doesn't get passed through to the collection views.

Comment: Yes it does. You only have to tell that you don't want to focus a table row, but its content. This can be done by implementing canFocusRowAtIndexPath method from UITableViewDelegate protocol.

Comment: This makes possible to go thru the first section items, right? How to make the down "button" focusing the items collections bellow the first?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem, and it turns out the Collection View I was using wasn't tall enough.

It should be tall enough to accommodate two cells on top of each other plus min spacing in between, and if it is tall enough then the Collection View Cell will appear in the top left corner of the Collection View in storyboard.

Once it is tall enough setting the flow to horizontal should work the way you want it to.